Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js
Node.js  version v14.21.3 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.
Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
I can't upgrade the node version to lastest version.
Is there any way to mitigate the error ?

Depending on your OS, you might be able to install a separate NodeJS, and run two versions in one environment. (Starter point for doing that: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-node-version-manager)
Then, you can install either a local or global Angular CLI to use the NodeJS v18, while keeping the other install and the rest of the project at whatever versions the rest of your project requires.

Install something like nvm or  fnm to handle different node versions for you.

If you are unable to upgrade your version of Node, which is the best solution, you could alternatively downgrade the version of the Angular CLI you have installed.

Thanks Everyone, was able to resolve the issue.

Clear the npm cache with the command:
npm cache clean --force
Install n package with the command:
npm install -g n
To update Node to the latest version:
n latest
this worked for me

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
